# Child of Constraint influence value doesn't recorded as keyframe

Tags: animation, constraints

I'm trying to make a reload Animation but when i set child of influence of magazine at start of animation at 0 and press I to record keyframes , and at ejecting part of animation when i set it to 1 and press I to record keyframes again nothing will happen it will always stay at last value i set it.

Here is the file of the project , i don't know what i'm doing wrong :
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's looks like you set the transform keyframes. To set a keyframe for influence, hover the mouse cursor over the influence value setter and press <kbd>I</kbd>.

Another way to do this - press dot icon over the influence value.

If the keyframe is setted, the value slider turns yellow.

[image]

Important: make sure, that final medium supports Blender's constraints

Comment: Hah thanks i didn't know i should hover my mouse over influence value then press I it's working now. thanks you so much.